# Javascript mobile redirect issue

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

Hi this has doing my head in for a couple of days now, I want to redirect to mobile websites for those checking the site from their devices with screen width of lower than 699. I am using this script for the redirection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
window.location = "http://www.mywebsite.com.au/mobile/";
}
//-->
</script>
```

The script is working fine when I am checking the site through firefox but not working in Dolphin browser..

It might be only my cell phone I have a Galaxy S2.

thanks in advance to anyone who can help me with this I really appreciate it!

New Update :-----ok this is getting very interesting. When I reduce the screen width to 599, the script works in  the Dolpin browser.(screen.width <= 599) ---

Comment: Since i don't have enough knowledge in mobile,  I have suggested to do this on server side by checking "Client" OS or User-Agent, instead of do this in javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest something like this using User agent detection

```
var isMobile = function() {
   //console.log("Navigator: " + navigator.userAgent);
   return /(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|windows ce|palm|symbian)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
 };
```

Redirect like this

```
if(isMobile()) {
       window.location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com.au/mobile/";
}
```

Comment: Kiran, does this redirect ipad users to the mobile site as well? I want ipad users go to full-site.

Comment: In that case remove ipad from the list.

Comment: kiranvj has shown you how you can use a simple regex to choose which types of devices will get redirected to your mobile site. With a little research about the different useragent headers different devices and browsers send in http requests, you can have total control over what browsers and devices are redirected to your mobile site. There is an exhaustive list here: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm

Comment: I personally use this string to detect mobile devices:    
  
`var mobile =  

(/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: Maybe I should add symbian like kiranvj has.

Comment: @kiranvj Thanks Kiran. The problem has been solved. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to give you thumbs up but well done. Cheers

Comment: @kiranvj ok the problem of the mobile redirection is solved but now when I checking the website through my PC the mobile website shows up instead of the full-site.

Comment: @MohammadMoezzi is the variable isMobile true in PC also?

Comment: @kiranvj I am not 100% sure to answer your questions. but this is what I am using `<script type="text/javascript">
var isMobile = function() {
   console.log("Navigator: " + navigator.userAgent);
   return /(iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|windows ce|palm|symbian)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
 };
 
if(isMobile) {
       window.location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com.au/mobile/";
}
</script>`

Comment: Sorry my fault, it should be if(isMobile()) not if(isMobile), corrected the answer.

Comment: @kiranvj Thanks. My website is down now. I am checking your solution again tomorrow and let you know. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

window.location is an object, so can you try the following:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.mywebsite.com.au/mobile/");
```

See [window.location.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Methods)

Answer (score 0):

My cell phone(MEIZU MX2) work fine.
I don't know version of Dolphin browser.
You can test 'screen.width'and'document.body.clientWidth'

I suggest you can write like this:

```
<script>     
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    checkOS = function (r) {
        return r.test(userAgent);
    };
    var PlatformOS = {
        isWindows: checkOS(/windows nt|win32/),
        isMac: checkOS(/macintosh|mac os x/),
        isAndroidPad: checkOS(/nexus 7|xoom /),
        isAndroid: checkOS(/android/),
        isIphone: checkOS(/iphone/),
        isIpad: checkOS(/ipad/),
        isWindowsPhone: checkOS(/windows phone/),
        OS: "",
    }
    if (PlatformOS.isIpad || PlatformOS.isWindows || PlatformOS.isAndroidPad) {
        location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com.au/pc/";
    }
    else if (PlatformOS.isIphone||PlatformOS.isWindowsPhone) {
        location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com.au/mobile/";
    }

    window.onload = function () {            
        var currWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        if (currWidth >= 699)
            location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com.au/pc/";
        else
            location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.com.au/mobile/";
    }
</script>
```